# How to set the front page to be the front page in Joomla

Tags: content-management-system, joomla, joomla1.5, frontpage

In Joomla how do I set the frontpage to be the front page (without being in the main menu). Currently whatever I set to be the default in the main menu is the first page, but I don't want the front page to be in the main menu.

[this si the site](http://www.dinotec.si/site/)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. I made the front page the first (default) page in main menu. Then I hid the main menu and made a new menu with things I want to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to do the same thing with one of the other menus or create a new menu..this way you have the flexibility of using your main menu on the front page